# Web Service Return Type/Value Standards

Tags: service, standards, web

Are there specific standards for the return message of a Web Service especially in regard to errors? I can imagine something like embedding error codes in a xml format but I didn't find anything specific for a established standardization of the return messages.

I also had a look at [OASIS](http://ws-i.org/default.aspx) but the amount of information is a bit overwhelming and I'm not even sure where to begin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start with SOAP services. You can get enough specs on SOAP

Comment: Well, I think SOAP:fault was what I was searching for. Thanks.